# Embed idml in another idml

Tags: php, xml, zip, adobe-indesign, idml

I'm working with some IDML files generated by Adobe InDesign which are, in short, XML representations of INDD files, InDesigns main file format.

I want to link/embed one or more IDML files into another single IDML "master" file.
I managed to link multiple INDD files into the master file in InDesign itself, but can not figure out how to link IDML files. I also found that it is possible to link INDD files into IDML files, just not IDML into IDML.

I need to be working with IDML as opposed to INDD because I have to be able to manipulate the files in an easy way.

Is there any way to link IDML files into other IDML files?
Or is there a possibility to convert my IDML files to INDD files with the help of PHP without having to use a real instance of InDesign?

**edit to claryfy why I need this done:**
My IDML master file is sort of a template for a site layout. The IDML files I need to embed represent single content boxes with specific layouts. To retain those layouts I deemed it best to just embed them into another document which is no problem with INDD but just with IDML.

Comment: Curious why you want to embed IDML in IDML?

Comment: @JoshVoigts I've edited the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Please provide references to where you found what is possible and what not. Also contact the vendor of that file/data format for your support options and ask there, too.

Comment: Thanks @hakre for the hint, i didn't even think about asking in the official adobe forums. I found out about the problems with the embedding by trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've seen, InDesign doesn't support "importing" IDML. It can only open it.
If the "single content boxes" are simple enough, you could use anchored objects and ICML.
To create the reference ICML file, just group all of the InDesign objects that would appear in the single content box. Then cut that and paste it into a text box so that the group becomes an anchored object. Adjust the anchored object settings so that your reference point and alignment point are both set for upper left corner of the box. Then export that text box as an InCopy Document. The result will be a linked ICML that encapsulates everything.